# Disable the 'Other' User Option From LightDM

Tags: rhel, lightdm, display-manager, alma-linux, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I am currently running `LightDM` on my `AlmaLinux 8.8` machine and I wanted to know if it's possible to remove the `Other` user option as shown below.

[image: LightDM Greeter]

I have already tried to edit the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file and set the following options, however with no effect:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-show-manual-login = false
greeter-allow-guest=false
allow-guests=false
```

I have restarted the `LightDM` service after saving my changes and even rebooted my machine, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-show-manual-login = false
```

This prevents you from manually entering the username to log in with.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Trudy, I did try this setting however I still have the ability to select the `Other...` option.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some greeters can have their own configuration files which can override the LightDM settings. From the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Optional_configuration_and_tweaks) page;

> Some greeters have their own configuration files. For example:
>
> lightdm-gtk-greeter: /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf (or you can use the lightdm->gtk-greeter-settings gui).
>
> lightdm-webkit2-greeter: /etc/lightdm/lightdm-webkit2-greeter.conf

If you can find the settings file for the greeter you're using, make the same edit as you have to the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file and restart the service.

Comment: Hello @kestrel, thanks for your input. I also noticed the information referenced in the Arch Wiki. I do have a `lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` config file. However, to my understanding this just covers graphical changes, like setting a wallpaper for example.